# Creating docker image out of a production environment possible?

Tags: php, docker, drupal, debian, workflow

I know it's very common to create Docker containers/images locally upfront of a project and deploy them to a certain environment (DEV/QA/PROD) once you have made changes. But what if you have a project already in production and you want to make local development possible/easier?

1. **General design question**

   Is there any (clever) way to clone an environment into Docker containers/images that are reusable on development machines? What would be the best way to do that? If that's not a good practice, how do you reproduce your prod environment on localhost?
2. **Example question**

   I have a running production server with Drupal running on Apache on Debian with loads of plugins and extensions (for PHP, for PHP5 particularly, for Drupal, for Debian, ImageMagick, etc.)
   Shall I create a single image with Apache inside Debian and Drupal on top? How can I achieve this in a single Dockerfile/`docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: Is it possible? Yes. Is it recommended? Not really. The term you're looking for is lift and shift. How do you do it? That could easily take an entire book to explain and doesn't fit the Q&A format of this site very well.

Answer (score -1):

1.Yes, there is a way to create docker images from production, but I'm afraid it's manual, and involve little understanding of Drupal and docker..

[Docker4drupal](http://docs.docker4drupal.org/en/latest/) is good starting point to make your docker-compose file

2.Most of the times it's wise to ceate multiple images and use them in one docker-compose file